# Symbol not found even when referenced class exist

Tags: java

I am very new to java.
Can somebody help why I am getting `error: cannot find symbol` error.

I have a class `User.java` which I am able to compile with success. `User.class` gets created in the same dir.

When I try to compile Another class `UserDao.java` which used `User`, it reports cannot find symbol error as stated.

```
vm@vm:~/UserManagement/com/tutorialspoint$ pwd
/home/vm/UserManagement/com/tutorialspoint
vm@vm:~/UserManagement/com/tutorialspoint$ ls
User.class  UserDao.java  User.java  UserManagement.war  UserService.java  web.xml

vm@vm:~/UserManagement/com/tutorialspoint$ javac UserDao.java
UserDao.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
public List<User> getAllUsers(){
           ^
symbol:   class User
location: class UserDao
```

**UserDao.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UserDao {
   public List<User> getAllUsers(){
   List<User> userList = null;
   try {
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really have a class named `user`?

Comment: You should probably `import User.User;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set a classpath, which defaults to be the current directory. So `javac` can't find the `.class` file for `User`.

Please take the effort to read the [classpath documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

The solution here is to either compile all classes at once:

```
javac UserDao.java  User.java UserService.java
```

Or set the classpath to the root of your packages:

```
javac -cp "/home/vm/UserManagement" UserDao.java
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But , if the class being compiled and class being referred are in same dir, still do we need to set CLASSPATH ? Earlier, i have compiled java programs, and never see issues as long as related java files are in same dir without setting CLASSPATH.

Comment: vm@vm:~/jersey/jaxrs-ri/api$ echo $CLASSPATH
/home/vm/jersey/jaxrs-ri/ext:/home/vm/jersey/jaxrs-ri/api:/home/vm/jersey/jaxrs-ri/lib


Now i am compiling :

vm@vm:~/UserManagement/com/tutorialspoint$ javac -cp "/home/vm/UserManagement" UserService.java
UserService.java:5: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
                  ^
whereas the GET class is present in /home/vm/jersey/jaxrs-ri/api/javax/ws/rs/GET.class

yet i am seeing this error.

Comment: @AbhishekSagar The ```-cp``` option replaces the environment variable. You could prepend a dot (```.```) to CLASSPATH and compile from the package root. But if you're using libraries, I would recommend using a build tool like apache maven.